# C++ why does getline() only work on the first instance of my function?

Tags: c++11, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

//These two functions work fine
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        if(!item.empty())
            elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}

//I think this function is where the problem is
std::string& singleSplit(const std::string* s, char delim='\0'){
    static std::string input=*s;
    static std::stringstream ss(*s);
    if(input!=*s){ss.str(*s);input=*s;}

    std::string item;

    if (std::getline(ss, item, delim)&&!item.empty())
        {std::cout<<item<<std::endl;return item;}

}
void setIntFrames(std::vector<std::string>& frames, std::vector<uint16_t>* Start, std::vector<uint16_t>* End)
{
    for(int i=0; i<frames.size(); i++)
    {
        Start->push_back(std::atoi((singleSplit(&frames[i],'-').c_str())));
        End->push_back(std::atoi((singleSplit(&frames[i],'\0').c_str())));
    }//this loop works fine the first time it passes, but the second time it just pushes back 0's into my Start and End vectors
}


int main()
{
    std::string x="0000-1200,1201-2359";//sample string of what alloted time frames in a day would look like
    std::vector<std::string>timeFrames(split(x,','));
    std::vector<uint16_t>startTimes; std::vector<uint16_t>endTimes;
    setIntFrames(timeFrames, &startTimes, &endTimes);

    std::cout<<startTimes[1]<<std::endl<<endTimes[1]; 
//setIntFrames() didn't set these correctly, I don't know why
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple scheduling program. I'm dealing with converting string x inside of main() into to arrays(vectors in this case) of start and end times. The way I'm trying to do it is first to split the original string into multiple strings(delimited by ',') then placed into the vector timeFrames. The next step would be to split those smaller strings, turn them to ints, and place them into either the startTimes vector or endTimes vector. I use setIntFrames for this step but I don't understand why it only works to set the first timeFrame.

I'm pretty sure the problems lies in my singleSplit() function, but I don't understand getline and stringstream enough to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your program doesn't compile.

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable in `singleSplit`.  The variable `item` was defined within `singleSplit`.  Pass that in by reference or something instead.  I don't think you posted actual code, maybe a test version.  It runs but gives me a memory fault.

Comment: `singleSplit` is indeed where the problem is: it's missing a return statement. You should enable all compiler warnings to avoid simple mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.  I changed pass arguments in as references and then pushing them back after use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

//These two functions work fine
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        if(!item.empty())
            elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}

//I think this function is where the problem is
void singleSplit(const std::string& s, char delim, std::string& first, std::string& second){

    std::stringstream ss(s);

    if (std::getline(ss, first, delim)){
    std::cout << "Found:" << first << '\n';
    }
    if (std::getline(ss, second)){
        std::cout << "Found:" << second << '\n';
    }

}
void setIntFrames(std::vector<std::string>& frames, std::vector<uint16_t>& Start, std::vector<uint16_t>& End)
{
    std::string first, second;
    for(int i=0; i<frames.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << frames[i] << '\n';
    singleSplit(frames[i], '-', first, second);
        Start.push_back(std::atoi(first.c_str()));
        End.push_back(std::atoi(second.c_str()));
    }//this loop works fine the first time it passes, but the second time it just pushes back 0's into my Start and End vectors
}


int main()
{
    std::string x="0000-1200,1201-2359";//sample string of what alloted time frames in a day would look like
    std::vector<std::string>timeFrames(split(x,','));
    std::vector<uint16_t>startTimes; std::vector<uint16_t>endTimes;
    setIntFrames(timeFrames, startTimes, endTimes);

    // std::cout<<startTimes[1]<<std::endl<<endTimes[1]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < startTimes.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << i << ':' << startTimes[i] << '\t' << endTimes[i] << '\n';
    }
//setIntFrames() didn't set these correctly, I don't know why
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
 $ a.out
0000-1200
Found:0000
Found:1200
1201-2359
Found:1201
Found:2359
0:0     1200
1:1201  2359
```